# Alternatives to pure quantifier logic

Tags: limits, logic, quantifiers, foundations

- Are there some alternatives for pure quantifier logic?

Pure quantifier logic is axioms and rules of inference added to proposition logic to result first order logic.

- Are there other axioms that do not use notions "for all" or "there exists", but can be applied to extend propositional logic, and can capture many things (at least quantification over $\Bbb R^n$) captured by pure quantifier logic.
- Is it possible to use limits to define quantifiers (that would allow at least quantification over $\Bbb R^n$)?

  I know that **limits** are defined in terms of quantifiers, but can they be redefined somehow?

Comment: When I was asking, I was thinking about philosophical part. I see too many uses of notion "for all" and "exists". I thought that it can lead to solid thinking patterns, it might lead to blinkers (horse tack) effect. Maybe if one uses weary different (for us humans) notions from "for all" and "there exists", he will see more, when doing same things. These "new" notions may be used in formally similar way that "old" ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is possible to make a foundational program that is based on a logic different (modal logics, or other more exotic systems) from classical first-order logic. 
But the classical framework has been judged the most convenient (or least inconvenient) for most people, and was designed to be the most natural way to express mathematical statements (such as the definition of limit).

It doesn't mean that it has been completely taken for granted, so people have investigated the rules of logic in the foundational questions, with [constructive mathematics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constructive+mathematics) refusing the law-excluded middle. More to the point, [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) has been designed precisely to remove variable quentification in mathematical logic, and thus investigate the precise power of quantifiers.

Now even for someone who would refuse all previous justifications, there are strong results like soundness, completeness and compactness that show the uniqueness of FOL (see [Lindström theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m's_theorem)).

For your precise example, in category theory, you can define notions in terms of diagrams, and have arrows to replace quantification over $\epsilon, \delta$. Other notions like being injective are similarly characterized by diagrams/universal properties. Category theory and logic serve different purposes and inform each other quite well (see the Curry-Howard-Lambek correspondence, and categorical logic for instance).

Comment: How can you say that there is no a priori justification for classical first-order logic? If you take any propositional statement $P$ with one parameter that has a well defined truth value when that parameter is substituted for any object (in the universe), then a priori it is either true for every object or false for some object, and classical quantifiers are defined precisely to express this intended meaning.

Comment: @user21820 Thank you for your observation. What I meant by that is, suppose that someone comes to you and say "well I find this wholly unnatural, and I think that X logic is the true logic underlying mathematics". Then your perfectly valid point could not be used as an argument with this person, but Lindström theorem could be. Maybe I should reformulate, or do you disagree with that?

Comment: Actually I do not think that my point can ever be invalidated. Note that even when studying various different formal systems, one still has to work in some meta-system, and the only meaningful meta-systems (as far as I can see) have classical first-order logic. Different people add different things on top of that, but nobody takes the law of excluded middle away, nor classical quantifiers. The reason is simple. Almost every important property of formal systems cannot be stated without quantifiers, and most require the law of excluded middle to be proven. [continued]

Comment: @user21820 "but nobody takes the law of excluded middle away" What? Constructive and intuistionistic mathematics do not exist?

Comment: [continued] For example, to state that a formal system $S$ is sound (if the meta-system cannot state this then it is utterly useless) one would have to say "for any derivation $D$ from initial assumptions $A$ that satisfies the rules of $S$, if $A$ are all true (in some context) then the conclusion of $D$ is true (in that context)" or something equivalent. No way of saying this can go without quantifiers over at least the natural numbers or strings.

Comment: You need to read my claim a bit more carefully. Constructive formal systems certainly exist, as objects in some meta-system, and when we investigate constructive formal systems (including comparing with classical systems) our meta-system uses classical first-order logic. One might disagree with having too strong a meta-system, but nobody disagrees that the meta-system better be able to do at least what $PA$ can do. Most logicians use the whole of $ZFC$ as the meta-system!

Comment: This argument implies that one has essentially only two choices: (1) say that it is meaningless to talk about soundness (2) allow the meta-system to have at least quantification over natural numbers or equivalent. I opt for the latter. And as I said earlier, it's not just about soundness; almost every meaningful statement we want to make about formal systems requires quantification. Similarly for LEM, we definitely want to be able to conclude in the meta-system that either a formal system is sound or not sound. Without LEM, we cannot.

Comment: In short, a priori the top-level meta-system (in case you have more than one meta level) ought to support classical first-order logic at minimum. Various non classical logics may be suited for various situations, but not for the top-level meta-system.

Comment: @user21820 Ok, you seem to have misread me. I didn't say you can get away from using quantifiers (although combinatory logic allow to do so), but you can use other logics for your meta-system (extensions of FOL, etc). You seem to agree with that since you say the meta-system "ought to support classical first-order logic at minimum", which says clearly that you can use something different from FOL.

Comment: @user21820 The point of "no a priori justification" was precisely to avoid "philosophical" discussions and stay on the solid grounds of mathematical statements.

Comment: I know my justification is philosophical but it's still "a priori justification" =) So you agree that the meta-system ought to have LEM? Then we agree, but I would explicitly say "extension of FOL" in the answer. Of course it's certainly good to mention that various non-classical logics are suited to describe some restricted situations, because special situations have greater structure, and some logics capture that extra structure which classical logic doesn't (like constructive logics as you mentioned).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37286/discussion-between-graffitics-and-user21820).